# Calibre search & replace

Tags: regex, calibre

I would like to replace `<space><letter><space>` with `<space><letter>&nbsp;`.

I'we try to replace `([aiowz])` with `&nbsp;$1` but in calibre it wouldn't work... it would put `$1` into text.

What should i put into replace field?

Comment: Did you try using `\1` instead of `$1`? They usually mean the same thing in regex, `\1` is the 'old way' though most languages are moving towards the `$1` format.

Comment: Is it an epub or mobi?

Answer (score 6):

In Calibre's Find/Replace window, \1 instead of $1 in the Replace box works well. Just don't forget to set Mode to Regex.

Comment: You just made my day.... 5 years later! Thanks; using the backslash fixed my problem.